# Recale plotly js z axis on zoom

Tags: javascript, visualization, plotly

plotly.js 2D histograms and contour plots automatically generate a z-axis range that accommodates the entire range of z values in the dataset being plotted. This is fine to start, but when I click-and-drag on the plot to zoom in, I'd like the z axis range to also zoom in to accommodate only the range of z values currently on display; instead, the z axis never changes. Here's a codepen (forked from the plotly examples, thanks plotly) to play around with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKGyJP

(codepen code inline:

```
var x = [];
var y = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i ++) {
    x[i] = Math.random();
    y[i] = Math.random() + 1;
}

var data = [
  {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: 'histogram2d'
  }
];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

)

This seems like pretty conventional behavior - am I missing an option in the docs somewhere to do this?

If there's no built-in option to do this, an acceptable alternative solution would be to manually set new z limits in a zoom callback, which is easy enough to implement per this example: http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/dogexw - in which case my question becomes, is there a convenience method to get the min and max z currently on display?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

plotly.js doesn't have a zoom-specific callback at the moment(follow this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/145) for updates).

One alternative would be to add a mode bar button updating the colorscale range:

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {
  modeBarButtonsToAdd: [{
    name: 'click here to update the colorscale range',
    click: function(graphData) {            
        var xRange = graphData.layout.xaxis.range,
            yRange = graphData.layout.yaxis.range;

        var zMin, zMax;

        // code that would compute the colorscale range
        // given xRange and yRange
        // for example given these values:
        zMin = 10;
        zMax = 20;

        Plotly.restyle('myDiv', {zmin: zMin, zmax: zMax});
    }   
  }]
});
```

Complete example: http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/JGvNjV